# Cannot start JBoss 7.1.1 Final

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, launch

I can't start my Jboss 7.1.1 final. Neither from eclipse nor from standalone.bat. I got JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME set (as recommended in other threads). I get the following trace:

```
18:33:42,651 INFORMATION [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
18:33:42,760 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
18:33:42,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Then nothing more happens. After the timeout, the server stops (it never started (was starting all the time)). Here's the launch configuration:

program args

```
-mp "C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone
```

vm args:

```
"-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss AS 7.1" -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost
```

This is the log from the standalone/log dir:

```
17:23:23,520 INFORMATION [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:23:23,972 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:23:24,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:23:24,000 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
file.encoding = Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = \
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless = true
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
java.class.version = 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;native;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;.
java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_73-b02
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version = 1.8
java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version = 1.8.0_73
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 25.73-b02
javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
jboss.bind.address = localhost
jboss.bind.address.management = localhost
jboss.home.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
jboss.host.name = cc03
jboss.modules.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules
jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
jboss.node.name = cc03
jboss.qualified.host.name = cc03
jboss.server.base.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone
jboss.server.config.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration
jboss.server.data.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data
jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content
jboss.server.log.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log
jboss.server.name = cc03
jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp
line.separator = 

logging.configuration = file:/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
module.path = C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules
org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log
org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
os.arch = amd64
os.name = Windows 10
os.version = 10.0
path.separator = ;
program.name = JBossTools: JBoss AS 7.1
sun.arch.data.model = 64
sun.boot.class.path = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\classes
sun.boot.library.path = C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
sun.desktop = windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command = org.jboss.modules.Main -mp C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level = 
sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
user.country = DE
user.dir = C:\dev\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin
user.home = C:\Users\Christian
user.language = de
user.name = Christian
user.script = 
user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
user.variant = 
17:23:24,008 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss AS 7.1 -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

This is the eclipse error:

```
Server JBoss AS 7.1 was unable to start within 30 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

But I don't think it has something to do with the startup timeout. It was at 500 or something intially. I had the same error with it.

Comment: Have you tried to look at your logs inside `<jboss_dir>/standalone/log` dir? Perhaps there you can find more information than only the one presented in the console.

Comment: @aribeiro added it in the post

Comment: What's the Java version you're using?

Comment: @aribeiro as you can see from the above traces it is 1.8.0_73

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it. I believe that's where the problem lays. AS 7.1 does not start on JDK8. See related [JBoss Developer community thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?tstart=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/223739?tstart=0) to [Tomaz Cerar](https://developer.jboss.org/people/ctomc), developer of both WildFly & JBoss EAP:

> There have been some changes in JDK8 that prevent AS7 and current version of EAP6 to start under JDK8.
>
> We have many JDK8 related fixes in WildFly so I would recommend you to use that.
>   As for EAP goes, the start up on JDK8 is fixed in upcoming 6.2 release.
>
> ...
>
> AS7.1.1 wont start on JDK8.

Furthermore, the issue that does not allow the startup of `JBoss AS 7.1`, using `JDK 8`, can be found [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2057).

In order to use `JDK 8`, [is advisable](https://developer.jboss.org/message/924115#924115) to upgrade to `Wildfly 8.2.0.Final`.